# Add this plugin... brain-jam

Tags: html, css, sharing, addthis

Guys I am about to get a massive headache here. First of all, I am working on a website and everything seems to be runng.  So, I had difficulties with making them links etc. so I tried to add the addthis.com plugin which would do all of that automatically. But, when I add that everything seemed to crash so I have made a quick jsFiddle to show you what I want. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/cSP9Q/1/ the problem is that I want to change those icons to mine which you can see on the first link and I just can't seem to change the spacings in between the icons. Furthermore, is there anyway of deleting the bubble with the counter because that just looks ridiculous.

Comment: Ok. Let me re-phrase this: does anyone know a script for sharing without changing my icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="social"><!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
    <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"><img src="your_image_url" /></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"><img src="your_image_url" /></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"><img src="your_image_url" /></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone"><img src="your_image_url" /></a>
        <a class="addthis_button_compact"><img src="your_image_url" /></a>
    </div>
    <!--javascript goes here-->
</div>
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/cSP9Q/2/) and [**Reference**](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381236-custom-buttons#different-image).

**NOTE:** your link `http://www.aasingercom.ipage.com/php/` doesn't work, anyway.